# Building WSP for SP 2010 designer customized aspx pages with multiple data view webparts

Tags: solution-package

We’ve designer access to the DEV and QA sites. We are able to customize some aspx pages and able to build some tabbed views with different dataview webparts.
Now we’ve a challenge to move these changes to production environment where we don’t have designer access. Is there any way we can build WSP with these changes?
Please help.
Thanks